# Rails - only commit transaction if client received response

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So, super weird use case.

Basically, a client created objects and syncs them to the server. The server persists them, and returns that same object with a UID. When the client gets that UID object, it deletes the client version and saves the server version.

I’m worried that the client will send the object, and while the server is validating, disconnect. Then when the client sends the object again, we have duplicates.

I could generate a client ID to avoid his situation and persist that with the server object, but I was looking into a way to only persist objects if the client successfully receives the response, so we know it won’t resend the request

I googled around, but I couldn’t find anything. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

So, as I thought, my answer really demonstrates a lack of understanding on how HTTP works. I suspected that it wasn't possible with this technology - and it isn't - but there's really an underlying problem that I should have addressed.

The correct answer is to have an id generated on the client that is also stored in the database. The reason is because this makes the request **idempotent** - that is, the client can resend the same request as many times as it likes without messing up the server.

Whenever the server gets a request to make a new object, it simply checks our client ids sent. If that object already exists, don't make it again, just return the server generated object. Simple!